# How to validate import functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a web app as a hobby using `nodejs` and `react`.
I have a file where I use some utilities functions, for example `foo`.

After using this function in some other files, I have decided to change the export and to wrap the function in an object, like `Util.foo`.

There was one file that I forgot to change the import statement to object instead of function, and I was calling foo() instead of Util.foo().

I couldn't catch it in my webpack build and not even in my unit tests, I cought it only when running the code and executing the appropriate function.

My question is, how can I avoid future mistakes like this? Are there any tools other than refactoring tools for this matter?

By the way, I am using Atom IDE.

Comment: Typescript can help to avoid these issues

Answer (score 1):

This should have been caught by your unit tests if this part of your code is covered completely.

Calling a non-existing function will result in an error along the lines of `undefined is not a function` and should fail your test case.

To avoid issues like this, make sure your test coverage is exhausting. A test coverage tool like [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul%5C) may by helpful in determining areas for improvement.

Comment: OK I will have a look at `istanbul`, but the unit test I wrote imported the `Util` correctly, hence the test passed. The function that uses `foo` doesn't have unit test because it is a 3rd party function which uses foo value as argument. I could have catch it only at integration test. But even though, is there a way to catch those typos before running the program? Something that validate these issues like compiler?